# Update column with new value in Netezza

Tags: sql, case, netezza

I have a doubt in solving this problem. My table has **model_name,device_type, count_device_type and NEW_device_type.**
I want to update my currently **device_type** column for every model to have only ONE device_type ( please see the example in the table)

```
**MODEL               DEVICE_TYPE    COUNT_DEVICE_TYPE          NEW_DEVICE_TYPE**

SAMUNG GALAXY S5      SMARTPHONE             100                SMARTPHONE
SAMUNG GALAXY S5      PORTABLE PDA           30                 SMARTPHONE
SAMUNG GALAXY S5      HANDHELD               10                 SMARTPHONE
```

I have tried this code, but can't catch the new value:

```
update tmp_BI_device_table a
a.device_type = b.new_device_type
from (
     select
     model
     ,device_type
     ,case when count(model)<40 then 
     (select distinct device_type from tmp_BI_dim_device_ref a group by model, device_type having count(model)>10 ) else device_type end as new_device_type
from tmp_BI_device_table
group by 1,2
 )
```

I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  12 : More than one tuple returned by a subselect used as an expression
```

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output ? and explain the conditions of the update operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the device type with the highest count, you can use `first_value()`:

```
select model, device_type, count(*),
       first_value(device_type) over (partition by model order by count(*) desc) as imputed_device_type
from tmp_BI_device_table
group by 1, 2
```